# Grafana Login Succes But Not Login

Tags: authentication, grafana

Grafana id pass correct but i can not login. I share screenshot.

Log:

lvl=info msg="Successful Login" logger=http.server User=admin@localhost,

lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/ status=302 remote_addr=x.x.x.x time_ms=22 size=29 referer=,

lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/ status=302 remote_addr=x.x.x.x time_ms=0 size=29 referer=http://x.x.x.x:3000/login

[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSbtt.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your Grafana isn't able to create any security cookie for your login.
Please check that your browser doesn't deny any cookie management.

Otherwise did you do any changes to the config files in ./grafana/grafana/conf?
You should have there a sample.ini and defaults.ini. In some cases you have a third .ini file called e. g. custom.ini.
Please check if the following line

```
# set cookie SameSite attribute. defaults to `lax`. can be set to "lax", "strict", "none" and "disabled"
cookie_samesite = strict
```

is either not set to none or disabled.

Comment: Have the same problem. It occures only when embed as `iframe`. Tried everything that suggested in Github - Nothing really worked. The only thing that worked was to enable `auth.anonymous`.. But this is not good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on HTTP, change **cookie_secure** to **false** in **custom.ini**

```
# set to true if you host Grafana behind HTTPS. default is false.
cookie_secure = false
```